# Variant of Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

Put $D=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|<1\}$ (open disk) and let $\Omega$ be non empty open simply connected in $\mathbb C$ and $\Omega \neq \mathbb C.$ Then Riemann mapping theorem tells us that
there exists biholomorphic map $f:\Omega \to D.$

> **My Question is:** Suppose that $\Omega$ is a nonempty open connected subset of $\mathbb C$ and $\Omega \subset (\mathbb C \setminus X),$ (where $X$ is closed connected and not singleton).  Can we expect to get a map $f:\Omega \to \mathbb C$ which is holomorphic , one-one and bounded ? If yes, how?

(We note that if $\Omega$ is simply connected then of course this is true by RMT)

Comment: If your $X$ has nonempty interior, then this holds. For an inner point $z_0$, we simply apply $f(z)=\frac {1}{z-z_0}$

Answer (score 2):

In general, it depends. But with $X = \mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega$ connected and not a singleton, things are easy. If $X$ is bounded, then $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus X$ is by the Riemann mapping theorem biholomorphically equivalent to the unit disk, and thus $\Omega$ is biholomorphically equivalent to the punctured unit disk. If $X$ is unbounded, $X\cup \{\infty\}$ is closed (in the Riemann sphere) and connected, and $\Omega = \mathbb{C}\setminus X = \widehat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus (X\cup \{\infty\})$ is biholomorphically equivalent to the unit disk. So under these assumptions, there are bounded injective holomorphic functions on $\Omega$.

---

If $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega$ is not connected, things are more complicated.

If $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega$ consists only of isolated points for example, the Riemann removable singularity theorem asserts that every bounded holomorphic $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ has an extension to a bounded entire function, and is therefore constant. We can iterate the removal of removable singularities, so if any iterated derived set of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega$ is empty, all bounded holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ are constant. We can thus assume that $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega$ contains no isolated points.

If $X$ contains a connected set $K$ with more than one point, then by the above $C\setminus K$ is biholomorphically equivalent to either the unit disk or the punctured unit disk, and hence $\Omega$ is biholomorphically equivalent to a subset of the unit disk, so then there is a bounded injective holomorphic function on $\Omega$.

If the complement of $\Omega$ is a perfect totally disconnected set, things become difficult. If the analytic capacity of $(\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}) \setminus \Omega$ is $0$, every bounded holomorphic function on $\Omega$ is constant, so no injective bounded holomorphic function on $\Omega$ exists. If the analytic capacity is positive, I don't know if there is always an injective bounded holomorphic function on $\Omega$, I suspect that to guarantee the existence of that, more than positive analytic capacity is required, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Thanks;I am confused slightly with notations. For me $\Omega \subset (\mathbb C \setminus X)$ ($X$ is closed connected in $\mathbb C$, not singleton  and so $\mathbb C \setminus X$ is open,  but this may be disconnected) and so I have chosen a one component of it; an so I have started with non empty connected  open set $\Omega$ with  the above property. In view of your second paragraph, can we say $\Omega$ is biholomorphically to punctured disk? Would you please clarify this; thanks.

Comment: @DF; thanks, according to your notations; in the conclusion or your second paragraph you are trying to say $\Omega$  is biholomorphically to punctured disk (not $\mathbb C \setminus  \Omega$ is bihlo...); please point out to me if I have missed something. thanks

Comment: I started writing my answer before you edited in that $X$ shall be connected (which makes things simpler). I've updated my answer accordingly now. Thanks for pointing out my mistake in what was the second paragraph. Of course it was not $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega$ which I meant, it was the complement of the segment which is biholomorphically equivalent to the unit disk (and hence $\Omega$ to a subset of the unit disk, but not necessarily the punctured unit disk).

Comment: @DF;  thanks;  when $X$ is bounded, why one can apply RMT? (would you please tell ,  what is $ \hat{\mathbb C} \setminus X$ ? is it simlply connected) thanks

Comment: Sorry, $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ is the Riemann sphere, didn't think of people used to other denotations. So $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus X = \Omega\cup\{\infty\}$. The Riemann mapping theorem applies to simply connected domains in the sphere (every simply connected domain in the sphere whose complement contains at least two points is biholomorphically equivalent to the unit disk), and a connected open set ($\Omega \cup \{\infty\}$ if $X$ is bounded, $\Omega$ if $X$ is unbounded) whose complement ($X$ or $X\cup\{\infty\}$) is connected is simply connected.